# Link/shortcut to create Chrome custom search

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

I've created a custom search in Chrome for a searchable page and need to share this.  Is there a way I can create a link or a shortcut that someone can click on that will automatically generate the search engine, rather than walking them through the steps of creating a search engine?

Something perhaps like:
chrome://newsearch?title=Cool%20Page&keyword=cool&url=http://www.coolpage.com/search?q=%s